# iOS UIKeyboardWillShowNotification userInfo when FaceUp/FaceDown

Tags: ios, orientation, uikeyboard

I'm having an issue, when the device orientation is FaceUp, the userInfo from the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification observer does not give me good values...

```
//WHEN FACEUP -> Wrong Values
Keyboard will show: {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}";
}
```

---

```
//WHEN PORTRAIR -> good values
Keyboard will show: {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 676}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 460}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}";
}
```

EDIT FOR MORE INFORMATION :

I'm using a UINavigationController, which supportedInterfaceOrientations returns 0.
I need it to returns 0 because I rotate manually a view, if I use UIInterfaceOrientationX the view rotation does not work properly...

EDIT 2 :

The orientation I'm referring to is not the interface's orientation, but the Device orientation. (The way you are holding your phone)

EDIT 3 :

This happen only when I push a new ViewController while faceUP, if I push it while portait, it works...
**AND IMPORTANT THING TO KNOW : When the bug occurs, the keyboard does not show**

EDIT 4 :

I have find a way to fix the bug, but **it will** most likely **be rejected by Apple** :

```
objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
```

**I'm still looking for a solution that won't be rejected by Apple**

Comment: Do you mean faceup or landscape?

Comment: faceup... in landscape more everything works fine just like in portait.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status bar orientation and determine if it is portrait or landscape, I'm using this macro

`#define IS_PORTRAIT UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)`

Comment: I'm not looking for the orientation (I already know it), just the correct values for the keyboard rect...

Comment: use the orientation to take it when you have inf values.

Comment: 1) this is not really a elegant solution - 2) The keyboard unfortunately does not appear either.

Comment: How you get the notification if the keyboard is not appearing ?